# get node id of field collection

Tags: nodes, entities

I have the following code. I am able to load the field collection item using entity_load_single. I want to be able to get the node id for a given field collection item. How can I achieve this?

```
function dc_car_guide_model($model_id)
{
    $model = entity_load_single('field_collection_item', $model_id);
    //How can I get nid?
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$model = entity_load_single('field_collection_item', $model_id);
$node = $model->hostEntity();
echo $node->nid;
```

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the data in a particular field used in Field Collection? A bit offside I know but am just curious.

Comment: Yes, the [Field API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7) works for fields on Field Collection entities as well. `field_get_items('field_collection_item', $field_collection, 'field_FIELD_NAME');` will return an array of values for a named field on that field collection entity. You can also use the [Entity metadata wrappers](https://drupal.org/node/1021556) (considered the new, slick way to do this :-p). Just specify that you're loading a wrapper for a `field_collection_item` instead of a `node`.

Answer (score 0):

Using EntityFieldQuery:

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->fieldCondition('field_MYCOLLECTIONFIELD', 'value',  $model_id, '=');
  $result = $query->execute();

  if (!empty($result['node'])) {
    $nid = key($result['node']);
  }
```

replace `field_MYCOLLECTIONFIELD` with the machine name of the Field Collection field on your node.